# PHP: Better to - Create hash table lookups, or encrypt/decrypt hash keys?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, encryption, hash

I'm building an app that works with two main elements.

The **first** is a segment that generates an entry with a with some hash key (eg. 5c2a4b5773500a0417f6e6d8299776d9cba7ead9) and inserts it into a table.

The **second** is a url that gets shared (eg. http://myapp.com/a/5c2a4b5773500a0417f6e6d8299776d9cba7ead9) that then comes back to the server, does a lookup against the fore-mentioned table, and executes some sort of predefined action, along with logging the incoming traffic.

**Here's my question:**

Doing a lookup with a 40 character length string key seems very resource intensive. Is it perhaps better to **encrypt** the ID of the row in the DB, thus creating a key, and then **decrypt** the 'hash'-key *with PHP* and do a single row lookup on the DB once it gets back to the server? *(Never really needing to store the hash/encrypted keys in the DB)*

Where are the pitfalls? Am I using the right terminology? Is there better ways to do this?

Comment: Doing a lookup with 40 characters (on an indexed column) isn't resource intensive.

Comment: I don't know the problem you are trying to solve, can you give us something more concrete?

Comment: Doing a database lookup on a ID (int), _must_ be faster than a string lookup. So do I create a hash after all seeing that indexing the table column is efficient, or do I encrypt the row ID needing to decrypt it later with PHP. ALSO, hashed keys is one way, encrypting is reversible... so perhaps down the road I might want the key to have a encrypted value..?

Comment: You're making this far more complex than it needs to be. Stop using PHP to do the heavy lifting of your data! That's precisely what a database is for!

Comment: Probably he's trying to develop a simple user registration or password reset, but he won't tell us because it's top secret.

Comment: Lol. You guys are a hoot. I'm just scared about running into scaling issues. I might end up having lots of people coming in on key, doing lookups on my main entry table and then the long string key ends up slowing things down. I don't have to much XP regarding table indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Consensus:**

- Doing lookups with a key on a **indexed table column** in the DB is
  already very efficient albeit 40 characters long.
- **Avoid** PHP from doing any **unnecessary heavy lifting**.
- Try not to **keep secrets** from SO.com users.